# Image Rendition in Picture Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, image-rendition

I have a requirement where I want to use the image rendition in the Picture Library in SharePoint on-premise version of SharePoint.

I am able to use it under Image library but no able to use it under the Picture library, is there a way we can use this feature in Picture Library.

Comment: Refer the below links it might help you.
1. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/image-rendition-in-sharepoint-server-2013/
2. https://mysharepointsolution.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/image-renditions-in-sharepoint-2013/

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the method provided by Divya if the problem persists, you can follow these steps:

1.Make sure publishing feature is enabled

2.A configured BLOB cache

3.You can run the below mentioned script to flush the Blob cache:

$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication ""
Write-Host "Flushed the BLOB cache for:" $webApp

More information:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/flush-the-blob-cache